# How to make a partly transparent overlay on image in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, masking

I have an image subdivided into slic superpixels. I'm using the gui to select some of these superpixels. 
Now I want to highlight the selected superpixels as transparent tiles.
 However I only know how to either a) use an mask to suppress parts of the overlay image  or b) how to set the entire overlay as tranparent.

a)

```
imshow(superPixelImage)
hold on;
h = imshow(overlayImage);
set(h,'AlphaData',overlayMask);
```

b)

```
imshow(superPixelImage)
hold on;
h = imshow(overlayImage);
set(h,'AlphaData',0.5);
```

Does someone know how to combine both such that the overlay is fully transparent on the non selected area and partly transparent on the marked superpixels?

Edit:
[This](https://github.com/mgarbade/semanticLabelingTool) is a beta-version of my matlab code that can be used to create semantic labels for an image database.

[image: a)]

[image: b)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert a matrix that match the size of your image to fill the 'AlphaData' parameter.

```
imshow(superPixelImage)
hold on;
h = imshow(overlayImage);
AlphaMatrix = (~im2bw(overlayImage)>0)*0.5 %creation of your AlphaMatrix.
set(h,'AlphaData',AlphaMatrix);
```

Comment: It works :). I didn't know that the `AlphaMatrix` could also consist of double values. Thanks a lot!